# $ n$-dimensional rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to find $n$ dimensional rotation matrix which corresponds rotation of an angle  $\theta$
around the 
$(n−2)$-dimensional subspace.

There is  the [n-dimensional rotation matrix formula](http://analyticphysics.com/Higher%20Dimensions/Rotations%20in%20Higher%20Dimensions.htm). (see equation $15$)

> $$I+(n_2n_1^T-n_1n_2^T)\sin(a)+(n_1n_1^T+n_2n_2^T)(\cos(a)-1)$$

where $n_1$ and $n_2$  are $n$-dimensional orthogonal unit vectors.

Can anybody explain how can I use this formula,  for $n=6$?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example application using Python / Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
    
# input vectors
v1 = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1])
v2 = np.array([2,3,4,5,6,7])
    
# Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization
n1 = v1 / np.linalg.norm(v1)
v2 = v2 - np.dot(n1,v2) * n1
n2 = v2 / np.linalg.norm(v2)
    
# rotation by pi/2
a = np.pi/2
    
I = np.identity(6)
    
R = I + (np.outer(n2,n1) - np.outer(n1,n2)) * np.sin(a) + ( np.outer(n1,n1) + np.outer(n2,n2)) * (np.cos(a)-1)

# check result
print(np.matmul(R,n1))
print(n2)
```

See the result [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxlj01LxDAQhu-B_IcBL6mbdknU9eRZ9roexUPslm2wmYR0Wqi_3umHyiqFwszDM-8bH1LMBDiENIHrAZMUUtyAxzQQjE1NMfdSjAaemFUuZzcpeDX653uDgrm95lbf6Xv9oA_6ceHzyefsQvlSt8GfCTi0jZeIrvOfjnxEKXDO4KD9fKjzjC4VxhzUaL4T-FfO9BxJodGjLeAW0LC70f-u3dJzpCUH3idIfm-lcGvldZDiuI7-3CB5mtRhEU-8PcIO1MziQE1WaDWaYi2ybYxGrrKUSVXvUbnij2MWZ3d9ZXMUL-vYs1SarW3dNvUH5KYfOpIiZY-0XAuOwtApOGl-NsvFL7Tz8AXICYEd&lang=sage).

Answer (score 1):

Depends upon what you have at your disposal for calculating?

If you have a scientific programming language, like matlab, you construct an $n\times n$ dimensional matrix from the above formula. For example, I is just the identity, $n_2 n_1^T$ is an $n\times n$ dimensional matrix obtained by taking the product of a column vector with a row vector, etc... The resulting matrix performs an orthogonal rotation by angle $a$ in the plane spanned by $(n_1,n_2)$ and with orientation given by that couple.

Answer (score 1):

With the notation  $$R(\theta)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}\cos \theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin \theta&\cos 
\theta\end{array}\right]$$ the rotation that you consider has the following matrix representation in an orthonormal basis $(
\vec{n_1},\vec{n_2},\ldots,\vec{n_n}),$ by blocks: $$\left[\begin{array}{cc}R(a)&0\\0&I_{n-2}\end{array}\right].$$ It is artificial to represent this rotation in the canonical basis of $R^n$, a natural basis should start from your $\vec{n_1},\vec{n_2}.$