# How an N dimensional rotation matrix can be constructed with more than one degree of freedom

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, rotations, angle

Say we have a point or a line in a three dimensional space, which we can rotate it around the origin by two angles, one with respect to axis 1 and the other with axis 2 or 3 (two angles(degrees of freedom) available to rotate this point around the origin.

I basically look for a general formula to construct a rotation matrix in n dimensions while it makes sense to me to have n-1 angels given as input, like the 3 dimensional case.

The formulations that I have found for n-dimensional rotation matrices have only a single degree of freedom (angle) to rotate over it. For example in [this quesion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2144153/n-dimensional-rotation-matrix) which obtains its formulation from [here](http://analyticphysics.com/Higher%20Dimensions/Rotations%20in%20Higher%20Dimensions.htm).

Do you know a general formulation of what I describe, for example in a 3 dimensional space?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're looking for, but it might be higher-dimensional analogues of Euler angles. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles#Higher_dimensions NB the number of parameters needed to specify a rotation is quadratic in the dimension, not linear.

Comment: A general rotation in 3D actually has three degrees of freedom: two to specify the rotation axis and one for the angle about this axis.

Comment: In the linked question, they are not examining all possible rotations. Only the subset of rotations leaving an $n-2$ dimensional subspace fixed (the equivalent to the axis of rotation). Even then, as amd indicated for 3 dimensions, there are actually more degrees of freedom than the angle of rotation. There are also the $n\choose 2$ parameters needed to define the $n-2$ dimensional "axis". But even that isn't enough: It is only in 3 dimensions that all rotations must leave some vector fixed. in 2 or 4+ dimensions, fixed subspaces other than $0$ are not necessary.